# read ng-init data from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS, I want to access ng-init data from contoller but always return undefined, here my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="IFuseController" ng-init="myText='Hello World!'">
....
</div>
```

**Angular controller**

```
uniqcApp.controller('IFuseController', function (IFuseService, $scope) {
   console.log("Cingda " + $scope.myText); //return undefined 
});
```

any idea?

Comment: Why would you be using ng-init this way?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit  see the big red box in most cases this isn't the right solution... what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: did you got solution

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your controller gets called on load, and that time you don't have value set for the variable **myText**.

You need to trigger an event once the text is loaded.

**DEMO**

```js
var uniqcApp = angular.module('uniqueApp',[]);
uniqcApp.controller('IFuseController', function ($scope){
   $scope.read = function(){
     console.log("Cingda " + $scope.myText); 
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="uniqueApp">
<div class="row" ng-controller="IFuseController" ng-init="myText='Hello World!'">
  <button ng-click="read()">Read initial value</button> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but what the best way to pass data to angular controller when it load for the first time?

Comment: you can place it inside angular constant/service/factory

Comment: @GustiArya did the answer help

Answer (score 0):

You can force to bind `ng-init` result to `$scope`:

```js
var uniqcApp = angular.module('uniqueApp', []);
uniqcApp.controller('IFuseController', function($scope) {
  var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller=IFuseController]'));
  var attr = el[0].getAttribute('ng-init');
  $scope.$eval(attr);
  console.log("Cingda " + $scope.myText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-app="uniqueApp">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="IFuseController" ng-init="myText='Hello World!'">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you init data on controller side ?
If you still want to do that , you can use $watch

```
$scope.$watch('myText',function(newVal){
   alert(newVal);
})
```